# x3dom chart does not display using d3

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, charts, requirejs, x3dom

I currently work on 3D diagram using X3DOM.js with D3.js to display data from API. So, this is the scenario:

1. I display the chart before sending the request to API (I call it first chart)
2. I send the request
3. I display exactly the same chart with new data (second chart)

I don't update the chart, I display the second chart below the first chart. The result is

1. sometimes the first chart does not display, but I can fix it by reloading the page
2. no request error
3. the second chart never display, instead I got a pixel-size black square. I can tell it is container of the chart (whose content does not display).

I take a look at html inspection and the `<x3d>` tag and all its elements are there. I use AngularJS and RequireJS. I borrow the chart code from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/camio/5087116). Anybody knows what actually happens?

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="CRating">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Main content -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Graph -->
            <div class="col-md-10" ng-controller="CGraph">
                <div id="bar">
                    <h2>Bar Chart</h2>
                    <div id="chartBar"></div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- Graph -->
        </div><!-- Main content -->
    </div>

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script data-main="js/main" src="components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</body>
```

**controller.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'bootstrap',
    'd3',
    'app'
], function($, bootstrap, d3, app) {
    app.module.controller('CRating', ['$scope', 'sharedProperties', function($scope, sharedProperties) {
        // code
        function initProject(response) {
            if (status == OK) {
                // code
                $.when.apply($, requestPool).done(function() {
                    sharedProperties.setData(sentimentData);
                    $scope.$apply($, sharedProperties.getData());
                    console.log('Data', sentimentData);
                }).fail(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
});
```

**graph.js**

```
define([
    'app',
    'd3'
], function(app, d3) {
    app.module.controller('CGraph', ['$scope', 'sharedProperties', function($scope, sharedProperties) {
        $scope.properties = sharedProperties;

        $scope.$watch('properties.getData()', function() {
            testChart();
        });

        function testChart() {
            function randomData() {
                return d3.range(6).map( function() { return Math.random()*20; } )
            };

            x3d = d3.select("#chartBar")
                .append("x3d")
                    .attr( "height", "400px" )
                    .attr( "width", "400px" );

            var scene = x3d.append("scene");
            scene.append("viewpoint")
                    .attr( "centerOfRotation", "3.75 0 10")
                    .attr( "position", "13.742265188709691 -27.453522975182366 16.816062840792625" )
                    .attr( "orientation", "0.962043810961999 0.1696342804961945 0.21376603254551874 1.379433089729343" );

            function refresh( data ) {
                shapes = scene.selectAll("transform").data( data );
                shapesEnter = shapes
                    .enter()
                    .append( "transform" )
                    .append( "shape" );

                // Enter and update
                shapes.transition()
                        .attr("translation", function(d,i) { return i*1.5 + " 0.0 " + d/2.0; } )
                        .attr("scale", function(d) { return "1.0 1.0 " + d; } );

                shapesEnter
                    .append("appearance")
                    .append("material")
                        .attr("diffuseColor", "steelblue" );

                shapesEnter.append( "box" )
                        .attr( "size", "1.0 1.0 1.0" );
            }

            refresh( randomData() )

            setInterval(function(){
                refresh( randomData() );
            }, 2500);
        }
    }]);
});
```

Comment: You should really post your code - your question is too vague without it.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a rush yesterday. I've posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a solution to this? The problem may be because of the combination requirejs + x3dom. Make sure you wait until dom is ready, load x3dom and after x3dom is loaded, work with it. A related post here: https://github.com/x3dom/x3dom/issues/382

In my case I'm doing something similar to this:

```
define(['require','domReady!'], function(require){  

    function runApp() {require what is needed for the app and run it}  

    require(['x3dom'], function() {  
        runApp();  
    });  
}
```